# Javascript object shorthand

Tags: javascript

I'm reading the following question:

```
(function(){
  var a = b = 3;
})();

console.log("a defined? " + (typeof a !== 'undefined'));
console.log("b defined? " + (typeof b !== 'undefined'));
```

it says *var a=b=3* is a shorthand for:

```
b=3;
var a=b;
```

So I solved another question

```
var foo = {n: 1};
var bar = foo;
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};

Question: What is foo.x?
```

So I'm assuming it's a shorthand for:

```
foo = { n:2 }
foo.x = foo
```

But, solution is other way around. It's undefined.

Can someone explain how is it undefined?

Comment: You're not being clear: _It's undefined_ What's undefined? `a`? Of course it is, a variable declaration being referenced outside of its scope can't be accessed.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts `foo.x` is `undefined`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts can you explain what does `foo.x = foo = {n: 2};`
 mean? maybe that will make things clear for me. I'm assuming it's foo = {n:2} then foo.x = foo;

Comment: @scraaappy thank you :-)